# Как сделать анимацию без исчезновения vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Как сделать эффект появления и исчезновения с помощью тега transition, но что бы элемент не исчезал, как в v-show="bool" и v-if="bool"?

Дополнение: Мне нужно проанимировать div, в котором список и div c кнопкой.

```
<transition name="fade" appear>
    <div class="menu-component" v-show="show">

        <ul>
            <li>item-1</li>
            <li>item-2</li>
            <li>item-3</li>
            <li>item-4</li>
            <li>item-5</li>
        </ul>

        <div class="slide-button">
            <button @click="show = !show">
                On/Off
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</transition>
```

Comment: Мне нужно проанимировать div, в котором список и div c кнопкой.

Comment: Весь этот блок делает перемещение в лево 300px, но кнопка в итоге остается видимой, в то время, как остальная часть скрыта за экраном.

Но из-за свойств v-if и v-show весь этот блок, с кнопкой исчезает.

Comment: Тогда, ёё нет на странице

Comment: Да, и она ездит вместе с меню.